# Getting Count Of select Query

Tags: sql, jdbc

My Need is to get the count of query that gets Executed. I got the Query to get Count Like

```
Select Count(*) from ( Select Query) from myTable
```

but the problem is when user enters a special character like the comma, period etc it shows error like  Syntax error at or near ')'. but from the user point of view, there is no ')'.

How do solve this? Is there any other way to get the count. My final output should  Syntax error at or near ',' or '.' etc if they are present in the Query

Comment: Assuming `from alias` should just read `alias` then this should not result in an error if the inner query is correct. And if the inner query is not correct, the error is justified. So what exactly is your question?

Comment: you can't have two froms in one query, if you want to alias inner query do something like this `Select Count(*) from ( Select Query ) alias`. If you want only row count you can use `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` after query as well

Comment: The select Query is the only thing user enter , I wrap it up with the above Query ,so if the inner Query is wrong i need to get error according to that not according to wrapped Query

Comment: Which DBMS product **are** you using? If you get an error in the combined query, you could run the user entered query again (knowing that it will fail) and thus get the real error message

Comment: i need to support postgres and mssql

Answer (score 0):

You need sub-query and for that you can use CTE(common table expression)

```
Select Count(*) from ( ) from alias-- your sql
```

this way you can do post sql server and postgre

```
with t1 as
 (
   Select Query ---- your sql code
 ) 
 select Count(*) from t1 --- count from alis
```